# How to replace values using list comprehension in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I was wondering how would you can replace values of a list using list comprehension. e.g.

```
theList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for i in range(len(theList)):
  for j in range(len(theList)):
    if theList[i][j] % 2 == 0:
      newList[i][j] = 'hey'
```

I want to know how I could convert this into the list comprehension format.

Comment: List comprehension is always going to create a new list. Not replace values in an existing one.

Comment: Can you paste expected output?

Comment: [[1,hey,3],[hey,5,hey],[7,hey,y]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do a nested list comprehension:

```
theList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[x if x % 2 else 'hey' for x in sl] for sl in theList]
```

returns

```
[[1, 'hey', 3], ['hey', 5, 'hey'], [7, 'hey', 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Code:

```
new_list2 = [["hey" if x %2 == 0 else x for x in row]
             for row in theList]
```

#### Test Code:

```
theList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
newList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for i in range(len(theList)):
    for j in range(len(theList)):
        if theList[i][j] % 2 == 0:
            newList[i][j] = "hey'ere"


new_list2 = [["hey'ere" if x %2 == 0 else x for x in row]
             for row in theList]

assert newList == new_list2
```

#### Or...

Or if you are literally replacing items in `newList` based on values in `theList` you can do:

```
newList = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
newList[:] = [["hey" if x % 2 == 0 else y for x, y in zip(row1, row2)]
              for row1, row2 in zip(theList, newList)]

print(newList)
```

#### Results:

```
[[10, 'hey', 30], ['hey', 50, 'hey'], [70, 'hey', 90]]
```

Comment: Technically, this isn't equivalent to the OP's example. For instance, this does not work if `newList` is initially different from `theList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a, b)
    return 'hey' if a % 2 == 0 else b

newList = [[f(a, b) for a, b in zip(r1, r2)] for r1, r2 in zip(theList, newList)]
```