# How can you replace all False values in list with empty strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following Python list:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, False, 10, 1, False, 20]
```

I would like to know which pythonic way would be used to replace all Falses with ''.
I have tried to find a .replace method but can not find something applicable to all items (as it happens in Pandas).

Python 2.7

Comment: `a[:] = ['' if value is False else value for value in a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    a = [2, 3, 4, False, 10, 1, False, 20]
    a = [each if each != False else '' for each in a];
    print(a)
```

Check out this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799698/how-to-replace-values-using-list-comprehension-in-python3).
I got this to work in an [online python compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler).
I literally just saw Peter's answer after I posted. Rip me.